# Auth0 'Unresolved Type WebAuth' in WebStorm

Tags: angular, angular5, webstorm, auth0

I have been having this issue with Auth0 and WebStorm for a while now. So I upgraded Auth0 to see if the issue was resolved. Here is my DEV environment:

- WebStorm 2017.3
- Angular 5.2.6
- Auth0 9.5.1 (upgrade from 9.0.2)
- Auth-Lock 11.6.0 (upgrade from 11.0.1)

I am seeing an error. WebStorm is identifying WebAuth as an `Unresolved Type`. Though the code works, it is annoying seeing this error. Does Auth0 or anyone have a solution for this?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `auth0-js` does not come with typescript types included. You can resolve this by simply installing the type definitions for `auth0-js`.

```
npm install @types/auth0-js --save-dev
```